# jQuery: choose a proper radio-button

Tags: jquery, radio-button

Here is the html code:

```
<div id="id1">
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="Male">Male</input>
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="Female">Female</input>
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="Unknown">Unknown</input>
</div>
<div id="id2">
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="Male">Male</input>
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="Female">Female</input>
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="Unknown">Unknown</input>
</div>
```

How to make the same radio button to be selected anytime for both `id1` and `id2` using jQuery?

Example: once you select Female from id1, Female from id2 is chosen automatically.

Example: once you select Male from id2, Male from id1 is chosen automatically.

I need it using jQuery.

Comment: so far what you tried ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code however you need to change the name of the input elements in your second div, otherwise they'll be part of the same group.

```
$('#id1 input,#id2 input').click(function () {
    $('#id1 input').eq($(this).index()).prop('checked', true);
    $('#id2 input').eq($(this).index()).prop('checked', true);
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/DcKKK/)**

Answer (score 1):

you have to change the names since radio buttons having the same name will be treated as within the group... the below works for me

http://jsfiddle.net/hcBUR/1/

```
<div id="id1">
<input type="radio" name="sex1" value="Male">Male</input>
<input type="radio" name="sex1" value="Female">Female</input>
<input type="radio" name="sex1" value="Unknown">Unknown</input>
</div>
<div id="id2">
<input type="radio" name="sex2" value="Male">Male</input>
<input type="radio" name="sex2" value="Female">Female</input>
<input type="radio" name="sex2" value="Unknown">Unknown</input>
</div>




$("div").find("*").each(function (index, elem)
                         {
                             $(elem).click( function () {


                                 $("[value='" + $(this).val() + "']").each(function (index, rd)
                                                                           {
                                                                                $(this).attr('checked', true);
                                                                           });

                             });
                         }
                         );
```